# For loop for calculating score, how to combine two methods

Tags: c#, for-loop

In my method `public static int PointsCalculator()` I seem to be unable to use my values from my two other methods in order to compare the values in the two array and give points.

I'm not really sure how to call or initialize the values to begin but tried to do a quick mockup.

My goal is to add one point for every user value in the `GetUserGuesses` method that is the same as the random values in the `RandomBingoNumbers` method.

```
class UserBingo // Creates a class to store all user related
{
    static int[] RandomNrs;
    static int[] userGuesses;
    static int num = 0;

    public static int[] GetUserGuess() // A method for collecting user guesses and displaying them (SPLIT THEM UP)
    {

        userGuesses = new int[10]; // Creates the array to store 10 user inputs 
        for (int i = 0; i < userGuesses.Length; i++)  // For loop itterates until 10 user values are put into the array
        {
            try
            {
                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (input < 1 || input > 25) // Only values between 1-25 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number between 1-25");
                    i--;
                }
                else if (userGuesses.Contains(input)) // Checks for repeated values
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have already entered {0}", input);
                    i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    userGuesses[i] = input;  //When they do meet the correct values
                    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for entering the number " + input);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Only numbers can be entered, ");
                i--;
            }


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userGuesses.Length; i++) // Loop to display all the input values in the array
        {
            Console.Write(userGuesses[i]);
        }
        return userGuesses;

    }
    public static int[] RandomBingoNumbers() // Method for creating 10 random integers
    {

        RandomNrs = new int[10]; // Creates an array to store 10 integer
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomNrs.Length; i++)
        {
            num = rnd.Next(1, 25);
            if (RandomNrs.Contains(num))
                i--;

            else
                RandomNrs[i] = num;



        }
        return RandomNrs;
    }

    public static int PointsCalculator() //Method for calculating score
    {
        int points = 0; // Integer to hold the amount of correct guesses

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            if (RandomNrs[i] == userGuesses[i]) // Check if the 10 user inputs is the same as the 10 randomized numbers
            {
                points++;
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your Numbers: \n [{0}]", string.Join(", ", userGuesses)); // Display user inputed numbers
        Console.WriteLine("Bingo Numbers: \n [{0}]", string.Join(", ", RandomNrs)); // Display the random bingo numbers
        Console.WriteLine("You got: " + points + "poäng"); // Display the amount of correct guesses
        return points;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding about how functions work in C#, may I suggest that you go run through some tutorials before asking questions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `using System.Linq`;
Lot of mistakes.

```
 if (GetUserGuess == RandomBingoNumbers
            ) // Check if the 10 user inputs is the same as the 10 randomized numbers
            {
                points++;
            }
```

should be

```
if (GetUserGuess().SequenceEqual(RandomBingoNumbers())
             // Check if the 10 user inputs is the same as the 10 randomized numbers
            {
                points++;
            }
```

And so many other mistakes, like the ***RandomNrs*** must be a static int[] declared outside the function. etc. etc..
This assignment is wrong `RandomNrs[i] = new UserBingoNrs;`. I'd suggest you to go over the entire syntax and usage of functions.

**UPDATE 1**

Instead of this

```
int[] RandomNrs = new int[10]; // Creates an array to store 10 integer
int[] userGuesses = new int[10]; // Creates the array to store 10 user inputs
```

you should use

```
RandomNrs = new int[10]; // Creates an array to store 10 integer
userGuesses = new int[10]; // Creates the array to store 10 user inputs
```

because RandomNrs and userGuesses  is already defined globally.

and instead of

`RandomNrs == userGuesses` and `RandomNrs != userGuesses`

you must use 
`RandomNrs[i] == userGuesses[i])` and `RandomNrs[i]!=userGuesses[i]`

```
else if (RandomNrs[i] != userGuesses[i]) // If user guesses are not equal to array points
                i--;
```

This will probably cause an infinite loop, instead of i--, do points--;

**UPDATE 2**

As simple as this

```
int num= rnd.Next(1, 25);
while(RandomNrs.Contains(num))
num = rnd.Next(1,25);
```

**UPDATE 3**

Change your PointsCalculator for loop to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
if (RandomNrs[i] == userGuesses[j]) // Check if the 10 user inputs is the same as the 10 randomized numbers 
{ 
points++;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, edited the question according to your suggestion, adding a static int at the top.But how do I assign them from the return method in my functions? 

Also rewrote the entire PointsCalculate function to work a little bit better.

Comment: Edited my answer @JsonDork

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot JsonDork. It is actually running properly now and collecting points, but I discovered a bug while I did that in the random method. 

I forgot to add a function for preventing the same randomized numbers to be put into the array, like I did in the userarray version but I can't replicate the behaviour with the random function. I tried some things myself but didn't understand. Edited the main code for the updates. @Suraj S

Comment: @JasonDork use SequenceEqual() only if you want to compare arrays as a whole ... Else use my code in UPDATE 1.

Comment: Ah, thanks Suraj, I've really learned a lot from this. Really grateful for your help.

Comment: Hey Suraj, I got another problem. I didn't get it to properly work in the end. I'm, trying to make it do this.  I want it to compare the first arrays element to the first element of the second array and then the second, then the third and so on until all elements of the second array. After that it should do the same with the second element of the first array. https://gyazo.com/ada094a1b519aa0e18088457803aa137 @ Suraj S